# Iframe src change with Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, iframe, src

I currently have some Javascript that looks a bit like this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
function changeSource(newSource) {
  document.getElementById('preview').src = newSource;
}
});
</script>
```

Then I have some HTML that looks like this:

```
<table border=0 class="colors">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a onclick="changeSource('http://www.test.com')"><img width="40" src="test.png"/></a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Then the Iframe section:

```
<table border=0>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><iframe id="preview" width="125" height="303" src="test.php" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" hspace="0" vspace="0"></iframe></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

However click on the image in the  tags the Iframe's source won't change. Why is it like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting an error because the function is a local method since you hid it in the onready function. There is no need for the onready call with that example.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
function changeSource(newSource) {
  document.getElementById('preview').src = newSource;
}
});
</script>
```

needs to be

```
<script>
  function changeSource(newSource) {
      document.getElementById('preview').src = newSource;
  }
</script>
```

Better yet, no JavaScript is needed! Use HTML like it is supposed to be used. Use the target attribute.

```
<td><a href="http://www.example.com" target="preview"><img width="40" src="test.png"/></a></td>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you so much. I will accept your answer once the time runs out.

Answer (score 0):

You are using jquery. Better make a perfect use.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // selecting anchor tag for table with class colors
    $("table.colors a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var newSource = $(this).attr("href");
        $("#preview").attr({"src" : newSource});
    });
});
```

No need of messing with html by adding **onclick** attribute or target attribute.
But html's **target** attribute is most preferable.

```
<table border=0 class="colors">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="http://www.test.com"><img width="40" src="test.png"/></a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```